# More efficient way to write this T-SQL query? Pass column from EXISTS statement?

Tags: sql-server

Is there a better way to write this? Primarily I'm referring to the `THEN` statement where I basically repeat the `CASE WHEN EXISTS` statement. It would be great to `SELECT DateJoined` inside the `EXISTS` statement and then use it outside that statement in the `THEN`. Is that possible?

```
SELECT
    Email,
    CASE 
       WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM _Subscribers
                    WHERE EmailAddress = Email)
          THEN (SELECT DateJoined 
                FROM _Subscribers 
                WHERE EmailAddress = Email)
          ELSE LastModifiedDate
    END as CreatedDate
FROM 
    [Optin Monster]
```

Comment: just do a LEFT JOIN instead of going to the table twice

Comment: So remove the EXISTS line entirely? I basically need to pick a date from one table if the subscriber is in it, and if the subscriber is NOT in that table, I need to get a date from another table.

Comment: hey that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Lamak for the help on this one. This did the trick.

```
SELECT
  om. Email,
  CASE WHEN s.DateJoined <> '' OR s.DateJoined IS NOT NULL
  THEN s.DateJoined
  ELSE LastModifiedDate
  END as CreatedDate
FROM [Optin Monster] om
LEFT JOIN _Subscribers s
ON om.Email = s.EmailAddress
```

Comment: Making some assumptions, but you cannot store a blank string in a date (or similar) column. Your logic now relies on an implicit conversion and the assumption that the implicitly converted value ('' becomes Jan 1 1900) will not exist in the DateJoined column. While this might seem like a valid assumption, there is no good reason to assume it.

Comment: One final comment - your case expression can be replaced and simplfied with "isnull(s.DateJoined, om.LastModifiedDate) as CreatedDate". Notice that I added the appropriate alias to 2nd column - best practices start early.

Comment: Thanks @SMor I can try it. This is SQL for Marketing Cloud so it's not exactly the same as MS SQL, but close. I can see if isnull() works, but it may not. The date fields I'm gathering will always be date fields because I set them up that way.There will always be a date and it will never be blank